# How much pressure (force) is needed to turn something into a black hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, pressure, astrophysics, estimation

I just curious to know "how much pressure/force needed to crush anything that it will get the schwarzschild radius $R=GM/c^2$.

Comment: Anything? We don't know of any process in the modern universe that can create a black hole smaller than ~3 solar masses.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have enough mass to create a black hole through its self-gravitation then you need to apply a pressure that is greater than the neutron degeneracy pressure of [degenerate matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter). Theoretical models of neutron stars suggest that this pressure is of the order of $10^{32}$ pascals. For comparison, the pressure at the centre of the Sun is "only" about $10^{16}$ pascals, and the pressure at the centre of a nuclear warhead detonation is (for a very short time) about $10^{15}$ pascals.

Comment: Smaller objects, such as Jupiter, will require much higher densities than neutron star matter and thus much higher pressures.

Comment: @KevinKostlan Why do you think that ? Once the applied pressure exceeds neutron degeneracy pressure, what else can prevent the object from collapsing ?

Comment: There is no limit to degeneracy pressure. It goes up with density endlessly. Collapse happens because gravity *also* rises to "infinity". But an Earth-mass ball of neutronium has (relatively) little gravity to oppose the extreme pressure and will explode.

Comment: Neutron degeneracy pressure cannot support anything more massive than 0.75 solar masses. This was established in 1939. Degeneracy pressure simply increases with density. It can't be exceeded in the way you suppose. The reason for the limit is General Relativity.